# Look for user generated answer and return TRUE or FALSE based on username and answer value

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have users that report what dates they are free in a Google form, and want to move the answers into a sheet that's easier to read so I can organize them.

I've searched everywhere - but so far I can't find anyone having this complexity in their formulas. I've tried anything I could come up with myself, but I found it too hard.

This is the answer sheet:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/qSIgmEs.png]

and this is the data sheet:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/UThUsI9.png]

LINK TO THE EXAMPLE SHEET (I've enabled comments): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p2CdP9mNW1nA8kWgwPoCfieNzFe4Br6KSR5d4zuyLxw/edit?usp=sharing

Now I want the datasheet to separate all the dates from the Answers sheet into TRUE or FALSE for each date.

Example:
`John` has marked that he's not available for work at `03.07`, and the result shows in `Answers!D2`. I want `Data!B6` to return `TRUE`.

I want all the names in `Data!` to reflect what they answered in `Answers!`, just in separate cells.

I imagine a formula that does the following:

1. Match the name in `Data!(current row):A` with `Answers!A:A`
2. Search the name-matched row in `Answers!` for any cells matching values from `Data!(current column):2`
3. Return `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on the existence of the value in any of the answers.

I have twisted my head over this on and off for several months now, but It's proving to be too complex for me. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in B3 cell and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(B$2:$2; TRIM(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(","; 1; 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3; Answers!A$2:E; {4; 5}; 0))); ",")); 1; 0))<>""; TRUE))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED

Please try, in B3 and copied across and down:

```
=not(iserror(find(text(B$2;"DD.MM");indirect("Answers!D"&match($A3;Answers!$A:$A;0))&indirect("Answers!E"&match($A3;Answers!$A:$A;0)))))
```